# How can I check that whether all the inputs have been filled correctly and then change it to green

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

[image]

As you can see in the picture, I have a word with 2 input fields and one word with 3. How can I make a variable that will check whether the word with 2 input fields has been filled out correctly. example: the word with 3 has 3 input fields, in the first one should go 1, in the second 2, in the third 3. How could I make it such that they remaining input fields until all 3 have been filled out CORRECTLY and then change the 3 input fields to a green button? This should be done for each word with their respective input fields. Right now I have it like this... but this will only check for each word and then make it a green input button:

```
function prepareCheck() {
$.getJSON('json_files/jsonData_' + ID + '.json', function(json) {
  var idxxx = 0;
       $(document).on('change', '.syl-input', function() {
           var rowCounter = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
           var inputCounter = $(this).attr('id');
           var jsyl = json.main_object.main_object.exercises[rowCounter].syllables[inputCounter];
           var jsylall = json.main_object.main_object.exercises[rowCounter].syllables;
           var valueInput = $(this).val();

       if (valueInput == jsyl) {
           var correctBtn = $('<button/>', {
              'class': 'btn btn-success buttonCorrect',
              'type': 'button',
              'id': "button" + CBC++,
              'html': valueInput
          });
          $(this).replaceWith(correctBtn);
              S.playRight();
              S.addRight();
       } else if ($.inArray(valueInput, jsylall) >= -1) {
            $(this).css({'color':'red'});
            S.playWrong();
            S.addWrong();
         }
    });
 });
}
```

how the JSON looks like:

```
{
"main_object": {
"id": "new",
"getExerciseTitle": "testforcounter",
"language": "nl_NL",
"application": "lettergrepen",
"main_object": {
  "title": "testforcounter",
  "language": "nl_NL",
  "exercises": [
    {
      "word": "Texel",
      "syllables": [
        "tex",
        "el",
        "",
        ""
      ]
    },
    {
      "word": "3",
      "syllables": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        ""
      ]
    }
  ]
},
"dataType": "json"
}
}
```

how the input fields are created (in case that should be usefull info).

```
var sylInput = $('<input/>', {
 'type': 'text',
  'class': 'form-control syl-input',
  'name':  +c++,
 'id': +idsyll++
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with the following code:

```js
function checkInputFields(key, value) {
 const validFields = [];  
 for(var i = 0; i < key.length; i++) { 
   if (document.getElementById(key[i]).value == value[i]) {  
     validFields.push('true');      
      if (key.length === validFields.length) {
       for (let k of key) {        
          // document.getElementById(k).style.backgroundColor = 'green';
          // Use these 2 lines, if you want to change the input text fields to Bootstrap buttons
          document.getElementById(k).setAttribute('type', 'button');
          document.getElementById(k).className = 'btn btn-success';
        }       
      }
    }
  }  
}

// JSON
const json = {
  row1: {
     keys: ["row1-field1", "row1-field2"],
     values: ['hello', 'world']
  },
  row2: {
     keys: ['row2-field1', 'row2-field2', 'row2-field3'],
     values: [1, 2, 3]
  }
}

// Row1
const row1Keys = json.row1.keys;
const row1Values = json.row1.values;
// Row2
const row2Keys = json.row2.keys;
const row2Values = json.row2.values;

const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
for (let input of inputs) {
 input.addEventListener('keyup', () => checkInputFields(row1Keys, row1Values)); // Row 1
  input.addEventListener('keyup', () => checkInputFields(row2Keys, row2Values)); // Row 2
}
```

```html
First row: <input type="text" id="row1-field1"> <input type="text" id="row1-field2">
<br>
Second row: <input type="text" id="row2-field1"> <input type="text" id="row2-field2"> <input type="text" id="row2-field3">
```

If you type hello, world in the first row, both input fields will be green. If you type 1, 2, 3 in the second row, all 3 input fields will be green. You can add so many rows you like, just save them into variables and pass them to the parameters of the function `checkInputFields`.

Comment: Sweet! This is what I am looking for, but would this also be possible with buttons? To change the input fields to buttons (boostrap class btn btn-success). can I make the variable like this, so I don't have to manually give up the rows etc? They are being made dynamically by the moderator. He/she decides how many (max of 4 input fields for each word) input fields are created and how many words.

Comment: @JJShaw you mean changing the input text fields to buttons? Sure it's possible but how would the user type his values then?

Comment: It should evaluate (so they are input fields) and when they are correct (all the respective input fields of a certain word) it should change those to green buttons (btn btn-success) to indicate you have those words correct and do not need to take any further action in the respective input field.

Comment: @JJShaw I am not quiet sure if I understand you correctly but I have edited the code to change input text fields to Bootstrap buttons.

Comment: yes exactly! exactly! exactly what you have now! But how could I implement this in my own code? I mean, you have 2 hard coded input fields and created the variables to put the answers in them etc. but what if it were to be dynamic and some moderator could decide how many input fields / rows could be made? For example: You have 5 input fields, 2 rows, what if the moderator decides to have 5 words (so 5 rows) with all of them 4 input fields? How would you implement this then? Don't get me wrong, your code works just like I was looking for, but how would u make it more dynamic?

Comment: @JJShaw you could create so many input fields as you want.Your variable will define which values should be correct. If you want to make it absolutely dynamic, I would recommend to use either a database, JSON or XML.

Comment: I do use a JSON file haha, therefore the question: How can I assign as many rows to the variables with their values of the input fields

Comment: @JJShaw I have edited my answer and added JSON to it.

Comment: Your code works. That's that, now however.. I cannot seem to get my head around something you keep on doing, could you clarify this please? You use const row1Keys = json.row1.keys; etc. but how would you adjust the variable if a moderator would ever change the amount of rows or the amount of values? your code works. That's that, but I would like to know how to resolve such issue.

Comment: @JJShaw if the moderator needs to change the keys or the values, he doesn't need to change anything in JavaScript. If you have a file for your JSON, he only needs to change the JSON file. Only if he needs to add another row, he will need to do it in JS. My code is not perfect, because if you want to make it absolutely dynamic, you need to run a loop that goes through the JSON. Then you wouldn't need to add all rows to your JS manually.